# OpenLDAP on ArchLinux users cannot change passwd

Tags: ldap, openldap, pam, passwd

I started an office and i NEED centralized login and home directories to work. Since all workstations are going to run Arch and problems with different LDAP versions I finally concluded the LDAP server also needed Arch.

I have done a completely clean install of Arch on the server and on a workstation. Both have Arch's "base" and "base-devel" package groups, NTP, OpenSSH & OpenLDAP installed, the server has nss-pam-ldapd as well. That's pretty much it right now.

1. I have followed the https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenLDAP but had to do the following things differently (and I have not set up SSL or TLS yet):

   - Before I copied DB_CONFIG.example I ran updatedb, and used locate DB_CONFIG
   - I had to run slaptest with -u option to supress database warnings
   - After running slaptest I did chown -R ldap:ldap on /etc/openldap/slap.d
   - systemctl start slapd fails, so does sudo slapd -u ldap -g ldap, but sudo slapd worked.
   - After running sudo slapd i killed slapd and chown -R ldap:ldap /var/lib/openldap but systemctl start slapd still failed.
   - after chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap i could finally use systemctl start slapd... i assume it was the schema folder that was not able to be read by ldap when started with ldap user.
2. Followed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LDAP_Authentication

   - I did not start or enable nscd
3. I can now log in with LDAP users on the workstation fine, and I can update the directory using my rootdn.

Problem: users cannot change password using passwd. LPAD returns:

```
password change failed: Insufficient access
```

/etc/slapd.conf (on server):

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
pidfile     /run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /run/openldap/slapd.args
access to attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by * none
access to *
    by self write
    by * read
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=testing,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=testing,dc=com"
rootpw      {SSHA}ntsD5qrvHJtMflarQPhJzapiEEnqH2/L
directory   /var/lib/openldap/openldap-data
index   objectClass eq
index   uid             pres,eq
index   mail            pres,sub,eq
index   cn              pres,sub,eq
index   sn              pres,sub,eq
index   dc              eq
```

/etc/openldap/ldap.conf (on client):

```
BASE   dc=testing,dc=com
URI    ldap://192.168.1.50
```

/etc/nslcd.conf (on client):

```
uid nslcd
gid nslcd
uri ldap://192.168.1.50/
base dc=testing,dc=com
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth (on client):

```
auth      sufficient  pam_ldap.so
auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
auth      optional  pam_permit.so
auth      required  pam_env.so
account   sufficient  pam_ldap.so
account   required  pam_unix.so
account   optional  pam_permit.so
account   required  pam_time.so
password  sufficient  pam_ldap.so
password  required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok sha512 shadow
password  optional  pam_permit.so
session   required  pam_limits.so
session   required  pam_unix.so
session   optional  pam_ldap.so
session   optional  pam_permit.so
```

/etc/pam.d/passwd (on client):

```
password    sufficient  pam_ldap.so
password    required    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok
```

So finally, my questions:

1. First off, where is the best place to read up on this kind of stuff?
2. Second off, how do I debug myself? Arch uses systemd, where is the syslog for systemd based systems?
3. What is the mlocate package with updatedb and locate? Do i need to use it? It is not mentioned in the archwiki, but mentioned in many other places.
4. And the actual question: Why can my users not change passwords with passwd

Answer (score 0):

on the client you must be uncomment in **/etc/nslcd.conf** like this :

rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

and change cn and dc as **rootdn** in **slapd.conf** on server

Comment: you don't need root access until the user can change (write) own password ( ```access to attrs=userPassword by self write``` ).